# Seeking program to highlight and calculate multiple areas on satellite image?

Tags: software-recommendations, digitizing, feature-extraction

I would like to calculate the area of all the parking spaces in my city (North Miami Beach). I would highlight the parking in two layers, commercial and residential, and then export it to Excel and calculate the area.

What would be an easy program to do this in? Something that I can save and is easy to manipulate/correct/edit.

I am new to GIS - right now I'm looking at QGIS, but I'm not sure if this is a good program to use.

---

I was planning on tracing the footprints of the parking lot manually, because image recognition seems like something very complex. I could start with a small area and if the results are good and everything works out I could move to an image recognition program for a larger area.

I was planning on going over an image of google satellite maps or an equivalent.

(Now that I have been playing around with qgis I see that i don't need excel)

---

The idea is to calculate how much all the parking space is worth and to see how much money could be generated if we reduced driving by let say 30%. I would take the average cost of commercial and residential property and multiply it by the area.

I understand this is a rough calculation.

30% of driving trips could be replaced by cycling or reduced with the use of future car sharing technology...I would like to have a economic argument for this besides for the environmental.

(cycling would also take up space, but less then cars)

Comment: Are you looking to trace the footprint of the parking lot manually or are you looking for image-recognition software that will do so automatically?

Comment: With any GIS program there would be no need to export to Excel to calculate areas. That's a basic function in GIS. QGIS is more than capable of meeting your requirements, free, and for the level of task you want to do should be fairly easy to learn with some basic tutorials out there (in the programs documentation or just online). Unless you want to do this automatically, in which case things get a whole lot more complicated.

Comment: Do you already have a file that includes the parking areas or are you looking to identify these yourself?

Comment: @ChrisW - Yeah, I think trying to differentiate parking areas from streets/sidewalks/etc. using spectral or pattern recognition would be a nightmare.  Although digitizing every parking space in North Miami...

Comment: @JWallace It's only about 5 square miles :) But yes, then you have to think about do you just do it as points with an assumed dimension for all of them, or do polygons and if so individual or just one that covers contiguous areas, do you count on-street spaces, really do two separate layers for commercial vs residential or just use an attribute... It's a good introductory exercise to GIS since it touches a lot of the basics.

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to GIS, I would recommend using Google Earth Pro (free to use, as of a couple months ago). You could [draw polygons](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148072?hl=en) in two different layers (residential and commercial). If Excel is only needed to calculate the area, you could simply [calculate the area with Google Earth](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/148134).